# Issue with indentation yaml file

Tags: yaml

[Image of exemple of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mRIp.png)

Hello
when I run the cat command it takes into account the indentation of the yaml code and therefore stays in EOF loop.

how can I make sure that the indentation is not taken in the cat

thanks for your help in advance

```
 UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
      sudo apt-get update -qq
      sudo apt-get upgrade -qq
      sudo apt install strongswan -y
      sudo cat >> /etc/sysctl.conf << EOF
            net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 
            net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0 
            net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
            EOF
      sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
      ipv4="curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4"
      Pipv4="curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4"
      sudo cat >> /etc/ipsec.conf << EOF 
        config setup# AWS
            charondebug="all"
            niqueids=yes
            strictcrlpolicy=no
            # connection to paris datacenter
        conn AWS
            authby=secret
            keyexchange=ikev2
            mobike=no
            compress=no
            type=tunnel
            left=%any
            leftid=$Pipv4
            leftsubnet="$ipv4"
            right=88.163.60.69
            rightsubnet=192.168.153.131/24
            ike=aes128-sha256-modp3072!
            esp=aes128-sha256!
            keyingtries=0
            ikelifetime=1h
            lifetime=8h
            dpddelay=300s
            dpdtimeout=120
            dpdaction=restart
            auto=start
            EOF
```

Comment: Completely unindent the `EOF` ?

Comment: Else replace `<< EOF` with `<< echo '` and the `EOF` with `'`. That will print the string out (`echo`), then that printed out text is piped to cat

Comment: because of the yaml indentation, the EOF is not taken into account I have to type it by hand

Comment: See the image exemple at the top

Comment: Yeah, the simplest solution would be to completely unindent the `EOF`'s. If this is not possible (I don't know much about YAML :@), I don'T know a solution ...

Comment: This is not really a YAML question. You enter a shell script, it executes as a shell script, it adheres to the syntax of a shell script – in this case, by not ending the heredoc if `END` does not occur at the beginning of the line (due to YAML preprocessing, `END` needs to occur at the base indentation of the literal, not at the beginning of the YAML line). This is how bash works. Asking „I use this language, how can I change its syntax“ is not really a sensible question. You chose to use the language, so you have to adhere to its syntax.